# Right way to use data type 'F' in SELECT-OPTIONS?

Tags: select, abap, dynpro

I want to have a `SELECT-OPTIONS` field in ABAP with the data type `FLTP`, which is basically a float. But this is not possible using `SELECT-OPTIONS`.

I tried to use `PARAMETERS` instead which solved this issue. But now of course I get no results when using this parameter value in the `WHERE` clause when selecting.

So on the one side I can't use data type 'F', but on the other side I get no results. Is there any way out of this dilema?

Comment: As far as I know, the type `F` is possible with `PARAMETERS` only if you use `NO-DISPLAY` e.g. `PARAMETERS param TYPE f NO-DISPLAY` (checked with ABAP 7.52 and 7.55), I'm surprised that it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Checking floating point values for exact equality is a bad idea. It works in some edge-cases (like `0`), but often it does not work. The reason is that not every value the user can express in decimal notation can also be expressed as a floating point value. So the values get rounded internally and now you get inequality where you would expect equality. Check the website "[What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://floating-point-gui.de/)" for more information on this phenomenon.

So offering a SELECT-OPTION or a single PARAMETER to SELECT floating point values out of a table might be a bad idea.

What I would recommend instead is have the user state a range between two values with both fields obligatory:

```
PARAMETERS:
   p_from TYPE f OBLIGATORY,
   p_to TYPE f OBLIGATORY.

SELECT somdata 
  FROM table 
  WHERE floatfield >= p_from AND floatfield <= p_to.
```

But another solution you might want to consider is if float is really the appropriate data-type for your situation. When the table is a Z-table, you might want to consider to change the type of that field to a packed number or one of the decfloat flavors, as those will cause you far fewer surprises.